# pyspark compare column in data (current_week ( YYYYXX) where XX is week number) with current system week number (today's week number)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a table with a column => data_week_number in format YYYYXX (example : 202040).

I want to ensure that I drop all the data older than current system week number. How can I get the system information to do the comparison?

I could see system date and week number in Spark but not in the format as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until [spark](/questions/tagged/spark) 2.4.6, you can proceed as follows:

```py
spark.sql("""select 202040 - 
             date_format(to_date(
             current_date, "dd/MMM/yyyy"), 'yyyyww') yearWk             
             """).show
```

Which returns:

```
+------+
|yearWk|
+------+
|   2.0|
+------+
```

As of [spark](/questions/tagged/spark) 3.0, `date_format` **no** longer accepts:

- `'w'` for *week of the **year*** or
- `'W'` for *week of **month***

You can set `spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy` to `LEGACY` to restore the behavior before [spark](/questions/tagged/spark) 3.0

Comment: I have two dates 2016001 2017002 ( jan 2016 and Feb 2017 ) how do i find months difference in them